# Flutter Navigator.pop Unexpectedly Pops Next Screen Despite Context Check

Tags: flutter, dart, http, async-await

I'm encountering an issue with Flutter's `Navigator.pop()` method. In my Flutter app, I want to ensure that a screen is only popped from the navigation stack if the user has not navigated away from it. This is particularly important during an asynchronous operation, such as a network request. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
final response = await http.post(...);
if (!context.mounted) return;
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

My expectation is that if the user navigates away from this screen before the `http.post` request completes, the `Navigator.pop()` method should not execute, thus preventing the app from popping the next screen. However, what's happening is the opposite: the next screen is still being popped, resulting in a blank white screen.

Has anyone encountered this problem, or can anyone suggest why the `context.mounted` check might not be preventing the screen from being popped? Is there a more reliable method to achieve the desired behavior?